# How to save formulas in R package

Tags: r, package, formula

How do I save multiple formulas in a R Package? Currently I have to run the as.formula code in order to retrieve the models, would be great if I can package them all in R.

I have saved package data in rda but don't know how to deal with "formula" class. Thanks!

Update: Saved a list of formulas in a list as rda file, now I can call them from the package now. Only the formulas are needed, not the environment in my case.

Comment: If the problem is that the formulas bring in their entire environment you could save a character representation, e.g. `format(myformula)`, instead.

Comment: This seems to work, at least if you want to load the formula in the globalenv: `fmla <- as.formula(y ~ x);save(fmla, file = "test.rda")`.

Comment: Formulas are tricky because there is an environment associated with each formula which can lead to scoping issues. It might be preferable to save actual model objects (and use `update` if you want to fit them to new data).

Comment: Thanks Rui! I save a list of formulas as rda and now I can call them from the package.